# Seudah Ha'mafsekes: Must one wash?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tisha-bav, netilat-yadayim-washing, meal-seudah

When I was a child, my parents always ate a [Seudah Hamafsekes ("separating meal")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seudat_mitzvah#Seudah_HaMafseket) before Tisha B'Av.
This meal consisted of bread, a hard-boiled egg dipped in ashes, and water.

A friend of mine recently told me that there is no obligation to wash for the Seudah Hamafseket. Is there a source that one need not wash for this Seuda?

Comment: Is an answer disagreeing with the premise acceptable? Kitzur Shuulchan Aruch 123:3 does explicitly mention that one should eat bread and an egg. https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.123.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en Or are you only looking for sources that say bread is not necessary?

Comment: You don't have to eat a meal then at all, so how could you have to wash?

Comment: @DoubleAA Based on the discussion in the Shulchan Aruch, it seems that the Seudah Hamafsekes is just the final meal before Tisha b'Av, so long as it's after Chatzos. The relevant customs should thus apply to whatever meal that may be.  https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.552.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Salmononius2 An answer disagreeing with the premise is not an answer that answers the question, unless all Halachic deciders say that one must wash.

Comment: @GershonGold Sometimes the best way to answer a question is to invalidate the premise.

Comment: @DoubleAA But if you ate a meal after midday with more than one cooked food, then presumably you would need to eat another, final meal (however we are going to define meal) to avoid having eaten an improper seudah hamafseket.